# Is it safe to combine data for zipcodes across different demographic sets?

Tags: gis, geospatial, zipcode

My team is working with demographics data across different data sources (some paid sources and some free data sources available online). Each of these data sources comes with a shape file and some attributes associated with each demographic area and could be defined across different cuts of time. However, when we display these attributes to our end users, we wanted to abstract the multiple datasources concept and show zip codes as a single demographic unit. We were planning to combine the attributes of all the datasources into one single datasource and point that to one of the shape files (For the time being, we are willing to look past issues related to granularity or precision in the definition of polygon across these datasoures. However, should we be concerned that the zip code to actual geographic area might not be consistent across demographics datasources taken across different cuts in time? E.g. ZipCode 12345 used to Map to an area in State A till 2010 but points to an area in State B for all datasets after 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was cross-posted on gis.stackexchange and was answered there (ref https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182790/is-it-safe-to-combine-data-for-zipcodes-across-different-demographic-sets)

There is a concern that we might be misrepresenting the data by making the assumption that the zipcode always maps to the same physical area and hence it would not be a good idea to combine datasources without running some tool that can map the data based on physical areas and not names of the zip code